# bash function dont recognize input

Tags: bash

I seem to have some problems executing this bash function from the terminal,

```
function sort () {

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; 
then
    word="$arg1"
    isolated="$arg2"
    file="output/$word _ $isolated_matches"
else
    word="$arg1"
    file="output/$word_matches"
fi
echo "$word"
echo "$file"
cat "$file" | while read line;
do
output=$(awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} /"$word"/ {print NR, $0}' "$line");
if [ $[#output] -ne 0 ];
then
    echo "File: " "$line";
    echo "----------------------------------------------------";
    echo "$output";
fi
echo $'\n';

done
```

I source the script in the terminal, and when i execute

```
 sort a a
```

My output becomes :

```
output
cat: output/ Is a directory
```

Why does it not recognize the input I am given it?

Comment: Multiple flaws - `"$arg1"` and `"$arg2"` don't get you the positional arguments in script, assignment to variable `file` is wrong. Passing shell variable to `awk` is wrong

Comment: `if [ $[#output] -ne 0 ];` is also wrong!

Comment: Try http://shellcheck.net/ to diagnose common problems before asking humans to review your code.

Comment: `$arg1` isn't what you think. Use `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

Just check this change.

```
#!/bin/bash

function sort () {

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; 
then
    word=$1
    isolated=$2
    file="output/${word}_${isolated}_matches"
else
    word="$1"
    file="output/${word}_matches"
fi

touch "$file"

echo "word : $word"
echo "file : $file"
cat "$file" | while read line;

do
    output=$(awk -v word="$word";  BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} /"$word"/ {print NR, $0}' "$line");
    if [ -n "$output" ];
        then
            echo "File: " "$line";
            echo "----------------------------------------------------";
            echo "$output";
        fi
    echo $'\n';
done

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
smily@Machine MINGK64 /d/test
$ sh testbash.sh
word : a
file : output/a_a_matches
```

Comment: I have taken out a space between $word and underscore in the file name

Comment: `-bash: output: syntax error: operand expected (error token is #output)`

Comment: awk don't like the variable input?

Comment: Actually, just use `[ -n "$output" ]` and don't worry about making an explicit length comparison.

Comment: And fix the quoting; e.g. `file="output/${word}_matches"`.

Comment: Edited. @kyodev pls check

Comment: well... you can install or use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)  to follow the [links of errors](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2002), it is very pedagogic

Comment: Thank you for your time.